# Proof of Fundamental theorem of Algebra using Liouvilles theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

I was going through the proof of Fundamental theorem of algebra using 'Liouvilles theorem'. **I have two queries/doubt in a proof**.

1. In the proof we assume that, $p(z) =0$ has no roots in $\mathbb{C}$ and then defined $f(z) =\frac{1}{p(z)}$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$. From this, **doesn't it directly follow that**, $$|f(z)|=\frac{1}{|p(z)|}≤1$$ so that $f(z)$ is bounded on $\mathbb{C}$.
2. Once we get that, $f(z) =\frac{1}{p(z)}$ is constant say $$f(z) =\frac{1}{p(z)}=k$$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$. where k is constant. **How, does it follows that**, $p(z)$ is constant? Isn't $k$ may be equals to $0$? If $k=0$ then what?

Please help me

Comment: Why would $\frac{1}{|p(z)|} \leq 1$ follow?  That's equivalent to $|p(z)| \geq 1$.  Why can't $|p(z)|=0.61239$?

Comment: $k$ can't be zero because it is $1$ divided by something, which can't be zero.  Now it follows that $p(z)=1/k$, a constant.

Comment: @Randall sir, since $p(z)$ has no root. So that, $|p(z)|=r$ where $r>0$. So $\frac{1}{|p(z)|}≤1$?

Comment: Why is $|p(z)|$ a constant?  Makes no sense.  And if your $r$ is $0.5$, then $\frac{1}{|p(z)|} = 2$ which is bigger than $1$.

Comment: @Randall sir, for your second comment. Yes I know that, $1$ divided by something is not zero. But, this means that, "something = finite number". So we must have $p(z)$ is finite for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$? and moreover 
as $\frac{1}{p(z)} =k$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$ , it must have same value for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Of course $p(z)$ is finite for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$.  How do you substitute in a $z$ to a polynomial and get $\infty$ as an output?  $p(z)$ is always a complex number, and $\infty$ is not.

Comment: And your "argument" showed that $1/p(z)$ is constant, so of course it is the same $k$ for all $z$.  That's what constant means.

Comment: Thank you sir, for explanation. Can you please, provide nice way to show (1) that is, to show $f(z)$ is bounded.

Comment: To see it’s bounded you use a very standard argument (that your proof source should have given!!). Assume $p$ is non constant. Noting $p\in\Theta(z^n)$ where $n\ge1$ is the degree it is easy to check $|p(z)|>1$ for all $z,|z|>R$ (some large constant $R$). On the compact disk $|z|\le R$, $|p|$ is never zero (by assumption) so it attains a strictly positive minimum $\delta>0$. It follows $|p|\ge\min(\delta,1):=\delta’>0$ for all complex numbers, so $1/|p|\le1/\delta’$ is globally bounded thus constant by Liouville’s theorem, and this contradicts the assumption $n\ge1$.

Comment: To reiterate the above comments, you have to use some kind of tools to conclude $f$ is bounded. It is not obvious unless you know some topology